# get my youtube account data react native app with supabase

Tags: react-native, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, supabase

im logging in with oauth2 with google auth and youtube . I can login with google but i want to login and get my youtube account when i login.

I noticed if you are trying to get personal data back from youtube then youtube needs to approve why you want it but my app isnt public yet and i was hoping i can at least do it if im just testing my app locally.

any thoughts or work arounds for this?

```
const performOAuth = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "google",
    options: {
      redirectTo,
      skipBrowserRedirect: true,
      scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
    },
  });

  if (error) throw error;

  const res = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
    data?.url ?? "",
    redirectTo
  );

  if (res.type === "success") {
    const { url } = res;
    await createSessionFromUrl(url);
  }
};
```